# A simple way to turn raw ascii data into sound

Tags: audio, signal-processing, file-conversion

I'm looking for method to process simple data into an audio output such as an mp3 file. The data is in the form of a two-column text file with a time signature in milliseconds and a level in millivolts.

Ideally the method would be script-able (with linux or unix tools). I have tried using Audacity to read raw data, however it seems to expect binary files, and doesn't seem to be flexible with sample rates etc.

Comment: is the time column uniformly spaced?

Comment: @jaket not necessarily, but I can process the data further using interpolation if need be

Comment: digital audio data is sampled at a regular rate. You're first going to need to  deal with that and then resample it to a more common rate for a sound card such as 48kHz.From there it's just a matter of dumping the data into a binary file and audacity would be able to read it as raw data. Or you can tack a 44-byte header on the front and call it a wav file.

Comment: You need to decide how you want to scale from millivolts to digital levels.